# RenderAction errors with No route in table only from certain pages, works on others

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am using `@{ Html.RenderAction("SectionNavigation", "Section"); }` from within a layoutpage. When I got to any page loaded from my `HomeController` the action breaks with the error `No route in the route table matches the supplied values.` but if I go to any page loaded from my `SectionController` it loads fine. My understanding of the `RenderAction` is that the first string is the Action to render and the second string is the controller name. What could be going wrong? Also, I am using Attribute Routing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have spent the last hour experimenting with trying to get this to work and finally figured it out. This is broken because I have a `RoutePrefix` assigned to the `SectionController` where this action lives. If I comment out the prefix everything works fine. I ended up moving it to a base controller that they all inherit from, which also has other general actions in it. Once it was moved and I updated the `RenderAction` to `@{ Html.RenderAction("SectionNavigation", "Base"); }` everything is working fine.